# I need to know how to access the characters that I want from an argument from the command line

Tags: bash

I need to know how to access to any character I want from an argument from the command line. Something like the cut command in bash, but from the command line.

For example if I write a date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, and I only want the characters `dd`, `mm`, and `yyyy`. How do I do that?

I've tried with the read command, but I don't know how to use it so well.

Comment: More details please! What should the input and output looked like? Also show what you've already tried. You can [edit] the question. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If you want to access `dd mm yyyy` separately, read the input into a string and split into an array using a *command substitution* and `tr`, e.g. `printf "enter dd/mm/yyyy: "; read -r datestr; arr=( $( echo $datestr | tr / ' ') );` now you can just `echo ${arr[@]}`.

Comment: You can use *"bash parameter substitution"*, examples here https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html

Comment: Can you give us more examples of what you're trying to do? It may help us.

Answer (score 1):

Bash provide a few ways to extract substrings (from command line input, or just variable).

#### Extract by fixed positions

```
# Process command line
input=$1
# Extract by position - MM columns
dd=${input:0:2}
mm=${input:3:2}
yyyy=${input:6:4}
echo "dd=$dd, mm=$mm, yyyy=$yyyy"
```

#### Extract by splitting (will work for cases like 1/2/2019)

```
input=$1
# extract first segment (DD)
dd=${input%%/*}
# Strip first segment from input
input=${input#*/}
# Extract second segment (MM)
mm=${input%%/*}
input=${input#*/}
yyyy=${input%/*}
echo "dd=$dd, mm=$mm, yyyy=$yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set `IFS` for `read`, though the question isn't totally clear.

```
IFS=/ read dd mm yyyy <<< "31/12/2019"
echo "$yyyy-$mm-$dd"  # -> 2019-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you, your answers were very helpful! I've solved my problem, sorry for not answering earlier. I did this

```
date=$1
day=$2

dd=$(echo $date | awk -F / '{print $1}')
mm=$(echo $date | awk -F / '{print $2}')
yyyy=$(echo $date | awk -F / '{print $3}')
```